# redirect/ %category%/%postname%.html to /%category%/%postname%

Tags: permalinks

My site was first built with html/css in 2000, and when I rebuilt it with WordPress in 2012, I kept the .html extension in the interest of keeping the same URLs. I'd like to get rid of it now and redirect the old html pages to the new extension-less pages.

My current permalink structure is:
/%category%/%postname%.html

I'd like it to be:
/%category%/%postname%

To do that, I tried deleting ".html' from the end of the permalink structure, then saving permalinks. Then, I put this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

But it doesn't work -- pages just give me 404 errors that way.

I took a look at the Yoast permalink redirection tool, but that only redirects to /%postname% -- I'm not sure if it's possible to modify the outputted rule to add the category before the postname.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I finally got it done. Here's what I did: 
(1.) changed the WordPress permalink structure to /%category%/%postname% and saved.

(2.) Added this to .htaccess: RewriteRule (.+).html?$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] (The rewrite rule in my original question didn't work for me.)

Now the .html URLs are redirecting to the new extensionless URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't flush your permalinks. Remove what you wrote in your `.htaccess`. Set what you had that was working before in the custom section of the permalink settings `%category%/%postname%.html`, save it, select 'plain', save it, then change it to your new settings `%category%/%postname%` save it, select 'plain', save it, then go to your custom setting and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Gregory! Do I add the 301 .htaccess redirection back afterwards? I'd like to make sure that Google understands that the old addresses have moved.

Comment: Either add 301 redirects to .htaccess or have Google reindex your site through webmaster tools.

Comment: Thanks. The new permalink structure works (afer flushing), but the old URLs don't redirect to the new, they just return 404s. I added the rewrite rule back to .htaccess but still get 404s.

Comment: Finally figured it out; needed the rewrite rule but not the one above.